# knex: the operator "undefined" is not permitted

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

im trying to use knex in nodejs whith a where that receive from a param, but the message 'TypeError: The operator "undefined" is not permitted' is showing, this is a part of my code and the console out

```
async retrieve(where, fields) {
    console.log(where);
    var _this = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //si no tengo where lo pongo como objeto vacio
        where = where || {};
        //si no tengo fields cojo los de defecto del schema
        if(!fields){
            fields = Object.keys(_this.schema.properties).map((key) => {
                return key;
            });
        }
        //selecciono
        console.log('este es el where justo antes de knex', where);
        _this.connection(_this.table)
        .where(where)
        .select(fields)
        .then((rows) => {
            resolve(rows);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            reject(GlobalMessages.db.dbError);
        });
    });
}
```

[image: knex function]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that `where` is actually a string `"{id_comercio:50}"` and not an object? That would explain the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit simplified version of your code:

```
async retrieve(whereClause, fields) {
  whereClause = whereClause || {};
  fields = fields || Object.keys(this.schema.properties);

  try {
    return await this.connection(this.table).where(whereClause).select(fields);
  } expect (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw GlobalMessages.db.dbError;
  }
}
```

Does it work any better? I cannot spot anything that would obviously cause that error though. It should happen during query building, but as you can see from this test code https://runkit.com/embed/mcb4fm8gmrhw the code above works just fine.

Maybe that is not the place where that error is thrown? You could add more debug prints to see what else might be happening in your code after that select row has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this thing: `where = where || {};` I've got the same error if passed a raw string instead the object.